# Does an insert statement's FROM clause support parameters?

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I have a select like this:

```
insert into F (fil) select count(*) from teste
```

*teste* isn't a table. It's a parameter captured in another *select* that gets the name of the table destined for the *FROM*. but the script exit said this error mesage:
*table or view does not exist*.

How do I pass a parameter into a from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FROM doesn't support parameters like this. Try writing a procedure to find the table name you want, then using EXECUTE IMMEDIATE or [the DBMS_SQL package](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_sql.htm) to execute a dynamic query that you put together.

```
DECLARE
    teste VARCHAR2(80); -- or all_tables.table_name%type
    result NUMBER(10);
BEGIN
    SELECT
        your_other_query INTO tableName
    FROM your_other_query_table
    WHERE
        your_other_query_where;

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' || tableName INTO result;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(result);
END;
```

Or, if you're using SQL Developer, this might work. Not sure if parameters are accepted here. Someone must physically type this value in this way. You can't use a query to come up with the *teste* value.

```
insert into F (fil) select count(*) from :teste
```

Comment: Barett, regarding second part of your answer: I think you mixed up bind variable (:teste) with substitutable variable (&teste) supported by client tool (SQL*PLus and etc). But they can't be used in named PL/SQL server code.

Comment: Hi Rusty, thanks for the feedback. The syntax I pasted works in SQL Developer. Yes, it is a bind variable. No, it can't be used in PL/SQL -- that's what I meant when I said someone had to physically type in the value.